# Missing TNS file for sqldeveloper Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, listener, tns

I just downloaded  the sqldeveloper for Oracle vers.12c, but i do not have any Listener or TNS file. I can not find it in my computer or anywhere. And I need them for the preparation of the Oracel certification

How can I get them?

Comment: Instead of using a local database (the setup is not trivial) you may use [Oracle Live SQL](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/f?p=590:1000)

Comment: The `tnsnames.ora` file is just used to resolve your database **alias**. You can connect directly, e.g. instead of alias `DB1` use the full string, e.g. `(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=mydnshostname)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=DB1)))`

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a **database**. Do you have it? If not, you'll have to download & install it. It contains files you need.

Comment: is the database contained in the TNS file?. It does not allow me to create a connection

Comment: TNSNAMES.ORA file contains "aliases" to databases you access. It doesn't contain the database itself (if that's what you meant).

Comment: so, i downloaded the sqldeveloper and that is all. But i can not make connections.

Comment: Once again: SQL Developer is a **tool** which lets you connect to a database and do "something" with it (create tables, insert data, update values, ...). In order to be able to use it, you need a **database**. For your needs, I guess that Oracle **Express Edition** (XE) is enough. Download it, read & follow installation guide. Alternatively, download prepared virtual machines (for VirtualBox) which have everything installed so - you can just start using it.